# C programming: how to input and output integers with more than 10 digits?

Tags: c

I want to take a 15 digit integer as input and show that integer as output in C language. Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: use `long long` as a type. That should work.

Comment: As Jean-Francois Fabre said you can use long long as a little add on the max value of a long long in C is at least `9223372036854775807`

Comment: Is necessary with most numbers of more than **9** digits.

Answer (score 2):

On most platforms, an `int` is at most 32 bit, which will get you 9 digits and some 10 digit numbers.  For larger numbers you need something that is at least 64 bit.  A `long long` is large enough for this, as `LLONG_MAX` must be at least +9223372036854775807.

You can read and write one as follows:

```
long long num;
scanf("%lld", &num);
printf("num=%lld\n", num);
```

Or, if you want to explicitly use a 64 bit integer:

```
int64_t num;
scanf("%" SCNd64, &num);
printf("num=%" PRId64 "\n", num);
```

Comment: All 9 digit numbers will work in 32 bit, but only some 10 digits.

Comment: When is a `long long` (which is a minimum of 64-bits long) not big enough to hold a value with 15 decimal digits (indeed, 18 digits; all  but about 8% of 19-digit numbers).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually you're right.  The standard say it must be able to hold a value of at least 9223372036854775807.  Updated to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

On `C`, you can the `double` to help with this. It can store about 15-17 digits. That should help with your program. `Double` is like a `float` , except it holds more digits.